# What formula solves this equation?

Tags: math, formula, algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I have the following data pieces, and am tying to solve for the item selling price:

W = net profit, 10% of item cost (X)

X = item cost

Y = flat rate fee

Z = variable fee, 15% of total selling price

S = selling price ?

What formula would you use in python to find S when W, X, Y, Z are known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: from your comment, it looks like you want to solve the equation:

[image]

[image]

So the code is `S = (1.1 * X + Y) / 0.85`

Comment: Thanks! However, Z is not known because it is 15% of S, which is unknown. Essentially, what I'm trying to answer is: "at what price (S) should an item be sold to generate a profit of X*0.1, if there is a known flat fee of Y, and an unknown fee of Z where Z is 15% of S?"

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot!